# iOS Log-in with LinkedInSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I need to provide an authorization with LinkedIn for my app.
I set up my app by this tutorial:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk
Then, Try to LogIn using this method:

```
- (void)login:(UIViewController *)controller{
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil];
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
     LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
     NSLog(@"Session LINKEDIN: %@", session.description);
     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"];
     if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {
     [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:url
                                         success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {
          NSData* data = [response.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
          NSLog(@"Authenticated user name : %@ %@", [dictResponse valueForKey: @"firstName"], [dictResponse valueForKey: @"lastName"]);
      } error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
          NSLog(@"Error : %@", apiError);
      }];
     }
 } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"%s","error called!");
 }];
```

}

My app requires to open LinkedIn app, when I enter there my LI login and password, it asks me to confirm my permissions, but then nothing happens.
What should I do to perform a correct authorization through LinkedIn?
(maybe, there is a way to do this with WebView as FB or Twitter?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to receive token using OAuth. Just did all the stuff followed by this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/)!

Answer (score 1):

Please use this link for linkedin login

//http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-linkedin-sdk-in-ios